# how convert xml to xamarin

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

Im first run android project with xamarin.

Im want convert code xml to xamarin or java

and visible after done event

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment2">
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pre"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack.

you can use the link for convert to java

[convert XML to java](http://www.xmltojava.com/)

and xamarin :
test it

```
 LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.parent);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

button1 = new Button(this);
                    button1.Text = "click1";
                    layout.AddView(button1, lp);

button2 = new Button(this);
                    button2.Text = "click2";
                    layout.AddView(button2, lp);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
                    text.Text = "text";
                    layout.AddView(text, lp);
```

XML :

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".BlankFragment2">
 
   

</LinearLayout>
```